# If I am only printing text (characters, bullets, indentation), is there an advantage to using LaTeX?

Tags: pdf, text-manipulation

I need to create a PDF with entries from a database (using C# .NET if it matters, but C# is not required).  The final document does have to be physically printed, but the printer does *not* get LaTeX, only the finished PDF that is made from the DVI.  It contains no math, no equations, nothing that requires special characters or images.  It has bullets and indentation but nothing "fancy."

Is there any advantage in using LaTeX here?  The LaTeX adds a layer of complexity I wanted to avoid for this particular application unless it is necessary.

I did not want to use eps, ps or anything like that.  I wanted to create a PDF with a PDF library.  Don't know which one.

I did not think this was a duplicate of "What's the point of LaTeX."  It is about text only documents with LaTeX.

Comment: The advantage: if you want to make it “fancy” later, you probably won't need to change the content in any way: just adding the appropriate settings should change the appearance the way you need

Comment: Why are you concentrating so much on the content? Your main problem is how to access and process the entries. If you have an export-to-pdf tool and the output is ok then use it, if you have no such export tool, then exporting to csv and using latex to handle this is one valid option.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Because I thought that was one of the main reasons to use LaTex.  When you have equations, for example, LaTeX might be the best tool.  If I have a paragraph with some bullets, it might be overkill.

Comment: Well that latex can create nice typography is one thing. But it is also a programming tool and so you can use it to automate tasks. I just created from a csv 7000 small labels with latex and typography wasn't what mattered but that the color could be adapted depending on values in the csv.

Comment: Another advantage might be, if you already know LaTeX, that you don't need to learn a new language or toolchain. The documents that you describe could be written in Markdown for example, but then you need to learn how to write Markdown and how to convert that to a pdf. Or you could use the 'document merge' functionality in Microsoft Office or LibreOffice, but then you need to learn how to use that functionality and how to automate PDF export from there, etc.